# Im getting error on terraform while deploying module "apigwmethodintegration_token"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on main.tf line 390, in module "apigwmethodintegration_token":
│  390:    "token"                          = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:function:${module.lambda_token.lambdafunction_name}/invocations"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.lambda_token.lambdafunction_name is tuple with 1 element
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on main.tf line 391, in module "apigwmethodintegration_token":
│  391:    "change-temp-password"           = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:function:${module.lambda_change_temp_password.lambdafunction_name}/invocations"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.lambda_change_temp_password.lambdafunction_name is tuple with 1 element
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Comment: Where is the `module.lambda_token.lambdafunction_name` coming from? Can you post the output definition that provides that value?

Answer (score -1):

At the offending lines, change:

- `module.lambda_token.lambdafunction_name` to **`module.lambda_token.lambdafunction_name[0]`**,
- and `module.lambda_change_temp_password.lambdafunction_name` to **`module.lambda_change_temp_password.lambdafunction_name[0]`**.